# ServiceStack catch-all route not getting some requests

Tags: mono, http-headers, servicestack

I have a specialized application that is looking to access the request stream and do its own processing.  This is working for all kinds of requests (Get, Post, Put, Delete, Head), but there is one client that a PUT does not find a route for.  I have the following DTO definition with ServiceStack running on mono / Centos:

```
[Route("/*", "GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD")]
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class S3Request  : IRequiresRequestStream{ 
    public string Path{ get; set; }
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

I used tcpflow to catch the http traffic on my centos machine.  The first output from tcpflow is for a client where the PUT is caught and my code called:

Working client tcpflow output:

```
192.168.079.001.61255-192.168.079.129.01301: PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: rack.s3devel.domain.com
Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 21:26:57 GMT
Authorization: AWS Y29tZXQ=:4ddNcEF11uXZYy2IlL4YUNiMn54=
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: DragonDisk 1.05 ( http://www.dragondisk.com )
Content-Length: 0
```

Non-working client tcpflow output:

```
192.168.079.070.58556-192.168.079.129.00080: PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: rack.s3devel.domain.com
Authorization: AWS Y29tZXQ=:Um+1V6iWvkMVbh12lyDAXGUQCo4=
Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 21:25:18 GMT
User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.6.12 Linux/3.10.13-101.fc18.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/24.45-b08/1.7.0_45
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I was thinking of hooking up a RawHttpHandler, but I don't see why I should need one?  Is there something in this header that makes ServiceStack not find the Put callback?

Answer (score 1):

Note the `[Route("/*")]` attribute likely doesn't mean to what you think it means, `*` outside of `{Var*}` just means the literal `*` and not any wildchar pattern you're assuming.

In addition you shouldn't have any other `[Route]` attributes on Request DTO's that have `[FallbackRoute]` (which is unnecessary/confusing) and when you don't supply any HTTP Methods it assumes it allows all of them so I would just change your Request to just:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class S3Request  : IRequiresRequestStream
{ 
    public string Path{ get; set; }
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

#### Using FormData forces preloading of Request InputStream

But it looks like your issue is due to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which populates the `Request.FormData` Dictionary that ServiceStack looks to check if it contains any POST Data Request overrides. Looking at `Request.FormData` forces loading of the Request Stream which prevents subsequent InputStream access in your handler.

#### Skip reading FormData when creating a Request

You can tell ServiceStack to skip looking at FormData when creating the Request with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest = true
});
```

#### Alternative Proxy implementation using a Custom Handler

The `SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest` config option was explained in the [latest v4.0.38 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#using-servicestack-as-a-proxy) which also provides a simple alternative to proxy a request with:

```
RawHttpHandlers.Add(_ => new CustomActionHandler((req, res) => {
    var bytes = req.InputStream.ReadFully();
    res.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}));
```

Comment: I fixed the FallbackRoute as you suggested and that works fine.  But I can't use the SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest, unless I'm mistaken, not with my current environment / version of mono / ServiceStack.  So far it has not resolved.  I tried the RawHttpHandler but so far it has garbled my responses.  Not sure what is going on there, but I'm playing with the RawHttpHandler to see if I can come up with a workaround for my situation.  Any other thoughts would be welcome!

Comment: I think one problem I have is that if I use a RawHttpHandler it may not be handling the auto-wired BasicRedisClientManager properly.     container.Register<ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClientsManager>(c =>
    new ServiceStack.Redis.BasicRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
container.RegisterAutoWired<RedisUsersCredentials>();  - I appear to be having problems with redis access as soon as the RawHttpHandler is involved?  Not sure if I'm doing something wrong to cause this.

Comment: You can still access any dependency in filters using `HostContext.TryResolve<T>()`. The `Config. SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest` was added in the latest v4.0.38 of ServiceStack.